# Xpath in docx, having parentheses as contains attribute

Tags: xml, xpath, openxml, docx, phpdocx

using a library for docx manipulation, phpdocx.com, I stumbled upon a problem which I can't solve with my poor xpath and docx knowledge.

In phpdocx, there are so called block variables which are used to mark a complete block, for example

```
$BLOCK_foo.bar$
Here comes a value
$BLOCK_foo.bar$
```

In order to locate and remove such blocks, they (phpdocx) use the following xpath expression:

```
//w:p[w:r/w:t[text()[contains(.,"BLOCK_foo.bar")]]]
```

The respective docx snippet can be found here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6bd998117b1a493dbaf7

So, I've debugged it and the above XPath query finds *one* node, `w:p`.

The first question, admittedly: why does it find only one match but there are actually two (the "starting" and the "ending" block).
Besides, the BLOCK_ occurence is ripped because of that bookmark thingie. How does that work at all?

But the actual question I have is, I have, don't ask, a block name like `$BLOCK_foo.bar(20).baz$`.

The xpath for this one, respectively, is

```
//w:p[w:r/w:t[text()[contains(.,"BLOCK_foo.bar(20).baz")]]]
```

This does not work as expected, it finds two nodes (both `w:p` though); where, I cross-checked that,

```
//w:p[w:r/w:t[text()[contains(.,"BLOCK_foo.bar20.baz")]]]
```

..correctly works on `$BLOCK_foo.bar20.baz`, so I, at the end, think it's a problem with the occurrence of the parantheses in the expression? On the other hand, the `contains()` value is wrapped in quotes so I'd say that shouldn't be a problem; but I've read that single quotes for example might also make trouble in `contains()` expressions...

The relevant PHP code block is https://gist.github.com/anonymous/490418104fdf5cd1a791. A concrete XML example can be found here, http://gist.github.com/anonymous/07eeddeb7d2f3c7db55b. The first "block" which spans from line 16 to line 74 works fine, while lines 101 till 166 doesn't, and the only difference I see are the parantheses...

Do you have an idea what I can do here?

Answer (score 1):

> so I, in the end, think it's a problem with the occurrence of the parentheses in the expression?

No, the problem is entirely different, it's a peculiarity of MS Word when storing data in OOXML format. Content is randomly split into separate `w:r` elements (so-called "runs"). As you can see here:

```
<w:r>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:cs="Arial" w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial"/>
        <w:sz w:val="22"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="22"/>
        <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>$BLOCK_</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:bookmarkEnd w:id="1"/>
<w:r>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:cs="Arial" w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial"/>
        <w:sz w:val="22"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="22"/>
        <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>foo.bar$</w:t>
</w:r>
```

The string "BLOCK_foo.bar" is not, as expected, in one `w:t` element, inside one `w:r` element, but split in half. That's why `//w:p[w:r/w:t[text()[contains(.,"BLOCK_foo.bar")]]]` only returns one `w:p` element.

For this other block you describe I suspect the very same happens, but you do not show the code, so all bets are off.

---

By the way, no, single quotes do not cause `contains()` any trouble in general. Where did you read that?

Comment: Thanks for this answer, find a more verbose code example here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/07eeddeb7d2f3c7db55b The first "block" which spans from line 16 to line 74 works fine, while lines 101 till 166 doesn't, and the only difference I see are the parantheses...

Comment: @AdrianFöder No problem here with separate runs. There's something I didn't get though: You say that `//w:p[w:r/w:t[text()[contains(.,"BLOCK_foo.bar(20).baz")]]]` "does not work as expected, **but finds two nodes**" - what does that mean? In any case, is there some code you can show from phpdocx?

Comment: yes it finds two nodes (what I would expect normally, because there are two occurrences); but in the cases where it works, it finds only one node. That's what's I don't understand here... So: working: one node, not working: two nodes. This is the code of phpdocx: http://i.imgur.com/yVtVq5U.png `$affectedNodes`.length is 2 in the erroneous case, 1 in the functioning.

Comment: @AdrianFöder Please do not link to an image containing your code. Edit the question and include it there. But not as an image, as code.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found it out. The parantheses are actually not a problem at all, I just didn't realize how PHPDocx handles the block substitution.

There's a sneaky, but evil Regex which just replaces *everything* from the variable until the next occurrence of the variable, just like `\$BLOCK_VARIABLE\$.+?\$BLOCK_VARIABLE\$`. So every occurrence of XML and stuff is stripped away and replaced with a single occurrence of $VARIABLE$.

In the next step, it searches for the occurrence of the variable via XPath and deletes the parent paragraph node.